# Directly write to encrypted file in Python

Tags: python, gnupg

In python, using the gnupg package, is it possible to take a value in memory, then write it an encrypted file rather than writing to file THEN encrypting?

I was hoping something like this would work:

```
import gnupg

gpg = gnupg.GPG(gnupghome='keydirectory')

l = [['a', '1'], ['b', '2'], ['c', '3']]

gpg.encrypt_file(l, recipients=['test@test.com'], output='encryptedfile.asc')
```

I was hoping there was a write concept like this to loop over line-by-line, but I can't find one.

```
with open('regularfile.txt', 'w') as file:
  for i in l:
    file.write(i)
```

Ideally, I could connect to a database and output a file by writing directly.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the `gpg.encrypt()` function instead of `encrypt_file()` and then write to a file.

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation for **the `GPG.encrypt` method**](https://python-gnupg.readthedocs.io/en/latest/gnupg.html#gnupg.GPG.encrypt) shows that is what you want.

```python
>>> import gnupg

>>> gpg = gnupg.GPG(homedir="doctests")
>>> key_settings = gpg.gen_key_input(
...         key_type='RSA',
...         key_length=1024,
...         key_usage='ESCA',
...         passphrase='foo')
>>> key = gpg.gen_key(key_settings)

>>> message = "The crow flies at midnight."
>>> encrypted = str(gpg.encrypt(message, key.printprint))
>>> assert encrypted != message
>>> assert not encrypted.isspace()

>>> decrypted = str(gpg.decrypt(encrypted))
>>> assert not decrypted.isspace()
>>> decrypted
'The crow flies at midnight.'
```